# Не выводится текст в angular с webAPI

Tags: angular, webapi

Мне нужно показать все имена, которые я записал в таблице Базы данных в поле Angular.

Моя БД:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sellers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

Я  делаю в WebAPI чтобы все названия  взяло с таблицы

```
 public class SellersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNames(string name)
        {
            using (var dataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                var query = from seller in dataBaseContext.Sellers
                            where
                            seller.Name == name
                            select seller;
                return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь  додаю в Ангуляре сервис:

```
 import { Sellers } from './sellers.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SellersService {
   formData : Sellers;
   seller : Sellers = new Sellers();
   constructor() { }
}
```

Додаю в app.module

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
......

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [SellersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Туда кудаа  хочу  додавать  названия в компонент

```
   import { SellersService } from './../../shared/sellers.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'left-region',
  templateUrl: './left-region.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-region.component.css']
})
export class LeftRegionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service : SellersService)
   {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

http

```
<div class="p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white">
  <input name="Sellers" #Sellers="ngModel" [(ngModel)]= "seller.Name" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Выдает  ошибку:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.Angular
```

Посмотрите что  не так я  делаю, почему  ошибка. И  правильно ли я  делаб  чтобы вывести  названия?

UPD:

```
       import { SellersService } from './shared/sellers.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TopRegionComponent } from './components/top-region/top-region.component';
import { LeftRegionComponent } from './components/left-region/left-region.component';
import { BottomRegionComponent } from './components/bottom-region/bottom-region.component';
import { CenterRegionComponent } from './components/center-region/center-region.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'user', component: UserComponent},
  {path: 'left-region', component: LeftRegionComponent},
  {path: 'top-region', component: TopRegionComponent},
  {path: 'bottom-region', component: BottomRegionComponent},
  {path: 'center-region', component: CenterRegionComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopRegionComponent,
    LeftRegionComponent,
    BottomRegionComponent,
    CenterRegionComponent,
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [SellersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

UPD2:
 left-region.component.ts

```
  import { SellersService } from './../../shared/sellers.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'left-region',
  templateUrl: './left-region.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-region.component.css']
})
export class LeftRegionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service : SellersService)
   {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: модуль нужно импортировать в модуль, где объявлен твой компонент, я не вижу `LeftRegionComponent` в `AppModule`

Comment: @overthesanity в апдейт весь код модуля выложил

Comment: так то лучше :) а в каком компоненте этот шаблон - `<input name="Sellers" #Sellers="ngModel" [(ngModel)]= "seller.Name" class="form-control">` ? а то ты так написал "http" - что ниче непонятно)

Comment: @overthesanity в left-region.component.html

Comment: покажи весь шаблон left-region.html

Comment: @overthesanity так это весь....

Comment: в смысле? у тебя `sellers` в сервисе, сам компонент left-region никоим образом не получает данные из сервиса и ты стучишься в несуществующее свойство

Comment: @overthesanity я  додал апдейт2.  забыл выложить . я  там  делыю в конструкторе. думал этого  достаточно...... Если нет. Можете  пример набросать что я не сделал. или не так сделал. спасибо

Comment: @overthesanity я перенес все что у меня  есть  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caqpw2 И тут  оно на то что у меня кричит тут не кричит