# Невыводится текст с БД в Ангуляре

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Мне нужно показать все имена, которые я записал в таблице Базы данных в поле Angular. Тоесть у меня есть таблица с  названиями. С нее я сделал выборку через WebAPI и теперь  хочу вывести через ангуляр все названия которые у меня есть в  БД

Моя БД:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sellers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

Я  делаю в WebAPI чтобы все названия  взяло с таблицы

```
 public class SellersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNames(string name)
        {
            using (var dataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                var query = from seller in dataBaseContext.Sellers
                            where
                            seller.Name == name
                            select seller;
                return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
            }
        }
    }
```

Код с Ангуляра я  занес на сайт - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caqpw2

Посмотрите и скажите что не так у меня. Почему не  выводятся названия....

Comment: пример нерабочий

Comment: @overthesanity где именно не  работает? В angular? У меня  работает. На сайт почему то не видит sellers.service

Comment: `Import error, can't find file:`
`./shared/sellers.service`, ну то что у тебя локально работает, это ж не значит что стекблиц работает :D

Comment: @overthesanity я посмотрел. путь правильно записанный. и то что оно не может найти на сайте это  другой вопрос. Я скинул туда свой код чтобы можна  было все что у меня есть  увидеть. если есть  желания можете посмотреть и сказать  что не так.  Если нет тогда спасибо за помощь.

Comment: а зачем ты создал дубликат своего [предыдущего вопроса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006978/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-angular-%d1%81-webapi)

Comment: к тому же никогда нет смысла разглагольствовать и лить воду, я пока по коду могу сказать, что документацию ты не открывал :( это не есмь хорошо

Comment: @overthesanity вы можете конкретно сказать в каком месте я документацию не открывал? и хватить и Ва  воду  лить. я конкретный код выложил. А вы второй день  отвечайте загальными фразами. Вы конкретно так и не сказали в каком месте я документацию не открывал.

Comment: документация большая, но есть тур героев, который если пройти то можно иметь представление о том, как работать с моделями

Comment: @overthesanity так я смотрел. если вы  об этом материале - https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2. Но как вы видете там  базу експортуют. тоетсь там создают. а мне нужно вытягивать уже созданую базу данных